# Getting error in QueryFactory in android

Tags: android, sparql

I am working in ontology in that I am use SPARQL query language in android. My sparql query is run fine in java but getting error when I run in android.

```
String query1 = "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"+
                "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"+
                "PREFIX my: <http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-20#>"+
                "SELECT ?Email ?ind ?ind1"+
                " WHERE {"+
                " ?ind rdf:type my:Accomodation ."+
                "?ind my:hasStarRating ?Email."+
                "?ind my:hasType ?ind1."+
                "FILTER regex(str(?ind),'HotelCityPark')"+
                "}";

com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query query = QueryFactory.create(query1);
QueryExecution exe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model1);

ResultSet RES = exe.execSelect();
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, RES, query);
```

I am adding following jar files

- androjena_5.0
- icu4j-3.4.5
- iri-0.8
- slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1
- jena-arq-2.11.1

I am getting error in `QueryFactory` method:

> NoClassDefFoundError .what can do for that or please suggest me if any other jar files is added

Comment: Jena requires more than just one jar. What happens if you use all of the jars that come with jena?  (I don't have experience with androjena, though.  This might not be the solution.)

Comment: i am using all the jar files but getting error in QueryFactory

Comment: you need to show the whole error.  As it's written, it's not clear what class is missing.

Comment: factorymethod  NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: whole error in logcat link-http://puu.sh/8MXVS.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You need the jar files from androjena; you can't mix and match androjena (a separate project) and use non-android jars that were released later.

Comment: We added all required jar
jar are Following
1-- Androjena_5.0
2-- icu4j-3.4.5
3--iri-0.8
4--slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1
 but  in eclipse doest not give permission to declare QueryFactory ,QueryExecution and ResultSet of  jena.
 i have also add one more jar it allows declaretion of Query Factory,Query Execution but android doed not allow its execution.
jar is ----jena-arq-2.11.1

Answer (score 0):

Download and insert arqoid binary and source code from [Androjena Project](https://code.google.com/p/androjena/downloads/list),then add all the jar file in to your project lib folder.